# Dump data from HTML to database(SQLite3) in Python Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am reading from mail and converting that in to normal data Using 'html2text'.
    Finally my output is like below...

```
Reservation Confirmation #184146

Last Modified On: 03/12/2014 03:24 PM

Pick-up Date:
03/18/2014 - Tuesday

Pick-up Time:
11:20 PM

Service Type:
From Airport

Passenger:
MR.Ramesh

Phone Number:
(000) 000-0000

No. of Pass:
4

Vehicle Type:
suv

Primary/Billing Contact:
some name

Booking Contact:
MR.Ramesh

Payment Method:
CC  0000

i am planing to dump this data to my DB(SQLite3).
```

How to do this in python,django
    Above data should be like this:
    ReservationConfirmation = 184146
    Pick-upDate = 03/18/2014 - Tuesday
    Pick-upTime = 11:20 PM
    Etc...

```
So, that i can dump in to corresponding fields in database.
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the HTML is just one giant `<p>` block, which means there wouldn't be any HTML tags to help your program make sense of the data, your best bet would probably be to parse the email as a string and use a couple splits.

First split() over "\n\n" (like `email = email.split("\n\n")`). This should yield a list with each key/value pair as a string, like `['Pick-up Date:\n03/18/2014 - Tuesday', 'Pick-up Time:\n11:20 PM']`.

Then split() over ":" (like `email = [entry.split(":") for entry in email]`). This should yield a list of key/value lists, like `[['Pick-up Date', '\n03/18/2014 - Tuesday'], ['Pick-up Time', '\n11:20 PM']]`

Finally, `parsed_email = {entry[0].strip():entry[1].strip() for entry in email}` should get you a dict of data that you could then load into SQLite, stripped of any extra whitespace, like the `\n`s from our example.